# CSS: how to make a div extend beyond a scrollable container

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a scrollable container - a div with `overflow-y: scroll` and `position: relative`.

I have a div inside it.

I have a second div, underneath the first, with `position: absolute`.

I would like the second div to extend beyond the bottom of the container div, but instead it increases the container's size.

If I remove the container's `position: relative`, then the second div does extend beyond the container, but it's positioned too far below (at the spot where it would have been positioned if there were no scrollbar).

I thought to give the second div `position: fixed`, but it's a problem, because the entire page may have a scrollbar, and when scrolled - I would like the second div to move together with its container.

The code:

```
<!-- container -->
<div style="position: relative; overflow-y: scroll; width: 400px; height: 400px; background-color: pink;">

    <!-- first div -->
    <div style="width: 20px; height: 800px; background-color: grey;">
    </div>

    <!-- second div -->
    <div style="display: block; position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 200px; background-color: red;">
    </div>

</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x341yvdn/

I prefer a CSS-only solution, but if it's not possible - then Javascript is also acceptable (vanilla or JQuery are both fine).

Comment: if the ```second div``` has ```position: absolute``` than it can't impact the container size.

Comment: Do you want the second div to be positioned directly below the first, 800px high div?

Comment: @AHaworth the second div should be positioned below the first, not necessarily immediately after it. At any case, the requirement I wrote is not completely accurate, I may post a separate question later. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for

```html
<html>

<body>
  <!-- container -->
  <div style="overflow-y: scroll; width: 400px; height: 400px; background-color: pink;">

    <!-- first div -->
    <div style="width: 20px; height: 800px; background-color: grey;">
    </div>

    <!-- second div -->
    <div style="display: block; position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 200px; background-color: red; top:400px;">
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I need, but I think I wasn't clear enough in my requirement. I'll accept. Thanks!